# Xamarin No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@color/accent ')

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, material-design

I am setting new xamarin forms. So for the android I am trying to set material design. Initially I had issue to park the styles.xml all that have been resolved. I have checked via the nuget that this xamarin.android.support.design and also xamarin.support.v7.Appcompat is already installed and up to date. What could else could go wrong or I did not set ?

Here is my styles.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ? >
<resources>
    <style name="DesignTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle" >true </item >
        <item name="windowActionBar" >false </item >
        <item name="colorPrimary" >@color/primary </item >
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark" >@color/primary_dark </item >
        <item name="colorAccent" >@color/accent </item > 
    </style >
</resources >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you following some tutorial?

The `@color/accent` is a variable you have to define yourself. This can come in handy so that you do not have to go by every place in your XML where you used the color, but you only have to change the value in the `@color/accent` variable.

To fix it quickly you can replace the `@color/accent` with #666666 for instance.

If you want to use the variables part create a colors.xml file under the resources folder. In these specify something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="accent">#666666</color>
</resources>
```

Now the `@color/accent` should be available. Of course instead of accent you can use any other name as well as you like.

Comment: yes I am following some tutorials on google related to xamarin forms.

Comment: How about this colorPrimaryDark, colorPrimary I guess is the same right?

Comment: sure I will do that cause you help me a lot to clear my doubt I think the tutorial miss one pre step to explain on this

Comment: do you have any idea how to apply this same material design on xamarin form ios?

Comment: You can't do that just like that. The Material design is something very Android specific. Of course you can try to approach it but it takes some iOS specific renderers etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126506/discussion-between-user5313398-and-gerald-versluis).